# How can I fix my Switch's resolution in docked mode?

Tags: nintendo-switch

When I opened up my Switch connected to my old (last-gen, I dunno) 2010 TV. It's an LG LCD TV (Model is 21,5 M227WAP. I don't know the actual model code or something though so go tell me the moment I post this), it looked as though my Switch was connected to a 4:3 TV and it sucked. I thought it was just gonna downscale it and fill up the entire screen looking stretched (I'm okay with that anyways) but no, not for this case. I'm looking for a suggestion on how to fix this.

Comment: The question has a lot of irrelevant details that can be removed to make a clearer question, making it more likely to attract better answers. Also, does the issue only happen with BotW or is it the Switch settings themselves?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried manually changing the screen size via [TV Settings](https://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/22331/~/how-to-adjust-the-tv-settings)?

1. From the HOME Menu, select "System Settings."
2. Scroll down the menu on the left-hand side of the screen and select "TV Settings."
3. Select Adjust Screen Size. (Dock the console and follow the on-screen prompts to manually adjust the screen size)

Additionally, changing the TV Resolution here may also help.

Comment: Well, I DID try adjusting it but it didn't address the situation. Oh --- and the TV I'm talking about is an LG TV, bought it exactly 7 years ago says the sticker at the rear.